# Why does Gorilla mux redirect when i have double slashes in my wildcard param?

Tags: go, slash, named-parameters, gorilla

Here my handler :

```
router.HandleFunc("/g/{gparam:.*}", MyHandler)
```

Bu when i pass something like "123://abc" as param it redirect and modify the param in url to "123:/abc".

is their a way to avoid that ?

Comment: You must want to url encode the gparam, changing the slashes to `%2F`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's intended behavior, and is configurable. By default, `Gorilla` mux will do path cleaning, i.e. removing double slash etc. for new router. You can left the double slash as is by:

```
router.SkipClean(true)
```

The [SkipClean](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.SkipClean) documentation says:

> ...
>   When true, if the route path is "/path//to", it will remain with the double slash. This is helpful if you have a route like: `/fetch/http://xkcd.com/534/`

Answer (score 1):

Having slash as param, may be your requirement. You need to escape the slashes as `%2F`.